# Accessing position in structure in python

Tags: python-3.x

i want to use an array N of 8 columns and df1.shape[0] rows and i wanna compare the values of an array state and antoher array action and increment the value of N at the adequate position [i,j] based on the value of state i and  the value of the action j as shown below but i got this error any recommendation :

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-66d1d4ab2df8> in <module>()
     84     elif(state[i]==4 and action[i]==0):
     85          #access column 6 of N represents state1 for action 0
---> 86         N[i:6]= N[i-1:6]+1
     87     else:
     88          #access column 7 of N represents state1 for action 1

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,8) into shape (1,8)
```

This is my code

```
N = np.zeros((df1.shape[0], 8))
#for i in range(1,df1.shape[0],1):
#N[df1['state'][i],df1['action'][i]]=N[state[i-1],action[i-1]]+1

for i in range(1,df1.shape[0],1):
if(state[i]==1 and action[i]==0):
    #access column 0 of N represents state1 for action 0
    N[i,0] = N[i-1,0]+1
elif(state[i]==1 and action[i]==1):
     #access column 1 of N represents state1 for action 1
    N[i,1] = N[i-1,1]+1
elif(state[i]==2 and action[i]==0):
     #access column 2 of N represents state1 for action 0
    N[i,2] = N[i-1,2]+1
elif(state[i]==2 and action[i]==1):
     #access column 3 of N represents state1 for action 1
    N[i,3] = N[i-1,3]+1
elif(state[i]==3 and action[i]==0):
    #access column 4 of N represents state1 for action 0
    N[i,4] = N[i-1,4]+1
elif(state[i]==3 and action[i]==1):
     #access column 5 of N represents state1 for action 1
    N[i,5]= N[i-1,5]+1
elif(state[i]==4 and action[i]==0):
     #access column 6 of N represents state1 for action 0
    N[i,6]= N[i-1,6]+1
else:
     #access column 7 of N represents state1 for action 1
    N[i,7]= N[i-1,7]+1
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "it didn't work" means? What exactly didn't work? What did it do?

Comment: Thanks for your remark i 've putted my error

Comment: @glibdud i think instead of puting N[i,j] i putted N[i:j] i want to enhance this code any recommendation